# What's the difference between jdbcType and sqlType for the @Column annotation?

Tags: jdo

Would someone please explain the difference between the `sqlType` and `jdbcType` of the the `@Column` annotation ?

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/annotations.html#Column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the document you cited:

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/annotations.html#Column

- jdbcType    String  ORM : JDBC Type to use for persisting into this column
- sqlType     String  ORM : SQL Type to use for persisting into this column

In general, JDBC should provide a mapping to the underlying SQL type, and you should code your JDO implementation to the exposed JDBC type.

This reference gives one example of where the distinction could be significant:

- http://osdir.com/ml/apache.db.jdo.devel/2005-07/msg00139.html

Here's some more documentation that might help:

- http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jdo/

> Q: So JDBC types are like standard data types while SQL types are
>   types specific to each datastore?

To answer you're question, here's what the JDO 3.0 Specification says, Section 18.4, Element column:

> http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdo-3.0-mrel3-eval-oth-JSpec/jdo-3_0-mrel3-spec.pdf
>
> The sql-type attribute declares the type of the column in the
>   database. This type is database-specific and should only be used where
>   the user needs more explicit control over the mapping. Normally, the
>   combination of jdbc-type. length, and scale are sufficient for the JDO
>   implementation to calculate the sql-type.

Comment: So JDBC types are like standard data types while SQL types are types specific to each datastore ?